# Referencing "type" in nodes returned by loadMultiple();

Tags: 8, entities

I know there are easier ways to sort nodes by type, using views, or using:

```
$query->loadByProperties(['type' => 'my_content_type']);
```

... but what I really want to do is return ALL nodes and then do different things based on the type field, like so:

```
$result = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')->execute();
$nodes = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node')->loadMultiple($result);

foreach ( $nodes as $node ) {
  if ( $node->type == "my_content_type" ) {

    // do something...

  } else {

    // do something else...

  }
}
```

However, my condition is never getting met, so I can only conclude that I am referencing the node type incorrectly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $node->type is for Drupal 7, to get the content type name (bundle) use `$node->bundle()` instead like `if ( $node->bundle() == "my_content_type" )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @berramou the solution is to use:

```
if ( $node->bundle() == "my_content_type" ) { ... }
```

Solved!